# How to access style present in .css file in angular unit test

Tags: css, angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am running unit test for angular app, I try to access style from .css inside unit test. I will let you know what I tried

```
 component.listedIps.length=0;
 fixture.detectChanges();

 let whitelistipsdiv=fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.divAllAllowedIPs'));

 //unit test for style, test for  background-color to be green
 expect(whitelistipsdiv.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor).toEqual('green');// to be darkgreen, here it is null
```

**.css file**

```
.divAllAllowedIPs {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: What is your problem ?

Comment: If component.listedIps.length=0; then background color style is green else the background color is pink. I ensured the above variable is equal to zero. Now I assert that background color is green

Comment: I am not able to access the background color style property in unit test

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I know I am late here but you can try. It will work 100%

```
  it('should have green background', () => {
    const e = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".divAllAllowedIPs")).nativeElement;
    expect(getComputedStyle(e).backgroundColor).toEqual('rgb(0, 128, 0)');
  });
```

I hope it'll help others as well who are looking for something similar question

Comment: hi, I always get (Expected 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)' to equal 'rgb(0, 128, 0)'.) even though im pretty sure the color is different